# Bootstrap pagination is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

I am trying to do pagination using bootstrap.
This my code code https://jsfiddle.net/x9u8u7h5/2/
Pagination is not working in my code.What I did wrong?

```
var roleList=[{
"sNo"     :"1",
"roleName":"Designer"
},
{
"sNo"     :"2",
"roleName":"Developer"
},
{
"sNo"     :"3",
"roleName":"HR Dept"
},
{
"sNo"     :"4",
"roleName":"Project Manager"
}
];

$(document).ready(function(){debugger
    $('#mydata').dataTable({

            });
            empRoles();
            $('.update').hide();

});

function empRoles(){
        for(var i=0;i<roleList.length;i++)
        {
        var table='<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>'+roleList[i].sNo+'</td><td class="roleName" id="name'+i+'">'+roleList[i].roleName+'</td><td><button class="btn dlt btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button></td><tr>';
        $('#roleListTable').append(table)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ryan says you're adding your data in an odd way. Take a look at this:

```
$('#mydata').dataTable({
    "data": roleList,
    "columns": [{
        "data": "sNo"
    }, {
        "data": "roleName",
        "className": "roleName"
    }, {
        "data": "roleName",
        "render": function() {
            return $("<button></button>", {
                "text": "Delete",
                "class": "btn dlt",
                "data-toggle": "modal",
                "data-target": "#confirm"
            }).prepend("<i></i>", {
                "class": "fa fa-trash-o"
            }).prop("outerHTML")
        }
    }],
    "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex) {
        $(row).attr("id", "row" + data.sNo);
    },
    "rowCallback": function(row, data, index) {
        $('td:eq(1)', row).attr("id", "name" + data.sNo);
    }
});
```

This does everything you were doing yourself via building the rows manually and it should give you much more control over your data. Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/gjohq4tu/) here. Good luck!

I think it could probably be optimised more but it does what you need at present.

Comment: Its working fine.But in my real application I am getting table datas from `database`.For that am using one function like this  https://jsfiddle.net/s1wnpnow/ .In this situation how can I pass datas inside of `.dataTable()` ? please clear my doubt .I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: You've got a couple of options: you can either get DataTables to get your data for you (check the commented out `ajax` section in the updated JSFiddle) or you can get the data externally to table and add the rows received from the ajax call (also in the updated JSFiddle on the `click` event of the button). It's important to use `DataTable` rather than using the older `dataTable` invocation though as it gives you much more control. Both methods are in the updated JSFiddle, hope that helps.

Comment: Why should I use`$("#getData").click()` directly I can get data from db right?

Comment: Yes you can, I added it to cover all options, the commented out `ajax` section does that, remove the button and relevant code and uncomment the `ajax` section to do that, I did say that in my comment. This is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/r1ujLd1d/

Comment: @annoyingmose Thanks.Why don't I use this method to get table data https://jsfiddle.net/7j8LLx0r/ ?Because using ` "column":[]` is getting confusion

Comment: @krish because your DataTable wouldn't be a DataTable (https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/g694bahy/)... `columns` can be confusing, but doesn't have to be. I've updated the latest JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/r1ujLd1d/) to do what you seem to need using Template literals.

Comment: Thank you so much :-):-)

Comment: I think that you'll need to test and possibly ask a new question as this comment thread is getting very long.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding your data to the table correctly.

Try using this
https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()

alternatively look at how to add data 
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/index.html